# flutter open images from file path

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using `image_picker` to get some images from gallery, and I saved the path of the images in a list, like:

`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E633FB78-77D3-4913-B37A-496BFBAAD00C/tmp/image_picker_EA6D2836-3EAD-438C-AEEE-21CB3500ED28-9410-00000706FA96031D.jpg`

how can I open the image from the path in flutter?

I tried `Image.file`, but it doesn't work, please help.

Answer (score 61):

The `Image` class has a `file` constructor for that

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html

```dart
Image.file(File(path))
```

Comment: I tried Images.file(path), but I got "Another exception was thrown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File'"

Comment: thanks for your answer! now i got this " Class 'Image' has no instance getter 'url'.", do you have any clue for this?

Comment: No, that sounds like it's from other code that what I provided in my answer. I would need more information.

Comment: i think the issue is from the carousel_pro package, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, I tried to use `Image.file(....)` on 
 `content://media/external/images/media/168155` string and it didn't work.
someone know how to use or convert this kind of path ?

Comment: Flutter can't read `content://...` urls directly. You need to resolve that in Java/Kotlin and pass the result to Dart. I don't know if there is a ready-to-use plugin available in pub.dartlang.org for that.

Answer (score 12):

For those who have tried `Image.file(File(path))` and have an issue with arguments, make sure you have imported `dart:io`, not `dart:html`, because sometimes it imports automatically.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and I solved it with the following code:
`Image.file(new File(StringPathVariable)`

Answer (score 4):

Suggested solutions do not work. Working solution in 2022:

```
import 'dart:io';

     Container(child:
            Image.file(File(savedImage!.path))),
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly `Image.file()` can only accept `ImageProvider<Object>`, and apparently `File(imagePath)` is categorized as `Image` type

So if `Image.file(File(imagePath))` fail, you can add `.image` at the end to turn it into `ImageProvider<Object>`, so the following code should work:

`Image.file(File(imageUri)).image`

Comment: Image.file(File(imageUri)).image does not work. It is marked as sytax error ecen after importing dart:io

Answer (score 0):

For those who have tried Image.file(File(path)) and have an issue with argument.
The issue is because of imported dart:HTML.
Try to import 'dart:io'. Then it will work fine