# Unable to load asset in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm sharing a picture that I've taken previously with the camera using `image_picker`. It works fine on the emulator but not on my device:

```
onPressed: () async {
  ByteData image = await rootBundle.load(team.avatar.path);
  ...
},
```

This is the error with the path:

> Unable to load asset:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/drodriguez.apps.Words/files/Pictures/scaled_2eccad3d-382e-462e-b124-b8fa06a2a32b791445736175256137.jpg

The image is being shown without errors so the path is 100% correct:

```
Image.file(
  _orderedTeams[index].avatar,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  height: 92.0,
  width: 92.0,
)
```

Do I need to add something else maybe on the `pubspec.yml`?

Comment: Does your load method insert a / at the beginning? If so, your initial path would be the root and it d make sense

Comment: yes, it shows `/storage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `rootBundle` to access files on the phone. The rootBundle (as said in its [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html)) only works for files packaged with the application when was built (probably saved on assets, declared on pubspec, etc).

If you want to load an image from the phone, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569317/flutter-open-images-from-file-path) maybe help.

---

## ANSWER

This function can read a filePath and return a Uint8List (a byteArray):

```dart
Future<Uint8List> _readFileByte(String filePath) async {
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
    File audioFile = new File.fromUri(myUri);
    Uint8List bytes;
    await audioFile.readAsBytes().then((value) {
    bytes = Uint8List.fromList(value); 
    print('reading of bytes is completed');
  }).catchError((onError) {
      print('Exception Error while reading audio from path:' +
      onError.toString());
  });
  return bytes;
}
```

And, to get a `ByteData` just:

```dart
var path = 'Some path to an image';
var byteArray = _readFileByte(path);
ByteData data = ByteData.view(byteArray.buffer);
```

(The answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124945/how-to-read-bytes-of-a-local-image-file-in-dart-flutter/57110584#57110584))

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't want to load the image, that's working already. I want to share it

Comment: Do you want an image that is on the phone (lets say, a photo taken by the camera), be converted to a `ByteData`?

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57110584/7120472) (not the accepted) is what you want. Read the image from the path and return a byte array. (After that you can convert the byte array to a `ByteData` with `ByteData data = ByteData.view(byteArray.buffer);`)

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. Feel free to add it on a different answer and I'll approve it as valid one.
Muchas gracias!